# Python Декодирование байтов в UTF-8

Tags: python-3.x

Есть функция, которая читает файл побайтового. Нужно перевести файл в кодировку UTF-8. Пробовал использовать такой код для чтения файла

```
def readTags(filepath):
with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
    byte = f.read()
    print(byte)

    while byte:
        byte = f.read()
        try:
            print(byte.decode('utf-8'))
        except Exception as e:
            continue
```

Но байты остаются в стандартном виде, т.е.

```
\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd1\x89\xd1\x8c
```

Как можно перевести данные байты в строку?

Comment: Заменить `print(byte)` на `print(byte.decode('utf-8'))` очевидно

Comment: Тогда скрипт выдаст синтаксическую ошибку:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Во-первых, это не синтаксическая ошибка. Во-вторых, байт 0xff действительно некорректен в кодировке utf-8. Значит или используется другая кодировка, или ваши байты некорректны и декодировать их в принципе невозможно. Однако в показанном вами «стандартном виде» нет никакого 0xff, значит, в-третьих, вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: Опишу всю суть программы. Есть картинка, допустим формата .png. Я пытаюсь скрыть сообщение в изображении используя запись моего текста в конец файла. На выходе картинка имеет байтовый класс.
Уже весь интернет перерыл ничего найти не могу

Comment: Ну тогда очевидно, что картинку декодировать невозможно, потому что картинка не является текстом в кодировке utf-8. Вам нужно найти способ отделить картинку от текста, выбрать только текст и уже его пытаться декодировать

Answer (score 1):

```py
byte = f.read()
```

в данном случае читает весь файл, весь же файл лучше и декодировать.

```py
with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
    bs = f.read()
    print(bs.decode('utf-8'))
```

только тогда лучше воспользоваться сразу текстовым режимом

```py
with open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    cs = f.read()
    print(cs)
```

Если же читать нужно именно побайтно, тут нужно понимать - utf-8 мультибайтовая кодировка, каждый символ может занимать как один так и несколько байт. Поэтому все равно получается не строго побайтовое кодирование.

```py
import codecs

decoder = codecs.getincrementaldecoder('utf-8')()

with open('utf.txt', 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        bt = f.read(1)
        if bt == b'':
            break

        print('byte:', bt, 'chars:', decoder.decode(bt))

    decoder.decode(b'', True)
```

```
byte: b'\xd0' chars:
byte: b'\xa1' chars: С
byte: b'\xd0' chars:
byte: b'\xbf' chars: п
byte: b'\xd0' chars:
byte: b'\xb0' chars: а
byte: b'\xd1' chars:
byte: b'\x81' chars: с
byte: b'\xd0' chars:
byte: b'\xb8' chars: и
byte: b'\xd0' chars:
byte: b'\xb1' chars: б
byte: b'\xd0' chars:
byte: b'\xbe' chars: о
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bytes = b'\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd1\x89\xd1\x8c'

print(bytes.decode())
Спасибо за помощь
```

Comment: Спасибо. А если предположим текст будет неизвестен, то каким образом можно вставить переменную с текстом внутрь b' '?

Comment: @Cucumber ваш `byte` из вашего кода уже автоматически «вставлен»

Comment: Cucumber вы картинку залейте